# Make own authorization page to access Google Apps

Tags: single-sign-on, google-oauth, google-apps

I hope you can direct me with my query.

I wish to create my own authentication method for users in my Google Apps for Work account. Currently I am using built in Google Authentication, however I wish to build my own authentication method in PHP, Phyton or .NET; language doesn't matter really. So I want users to go to the page I will create, then they will need to pass authentication and be logged to Google Apps.

I know SSO is the way to do it but after my research I found very little about how to achieve it with Google Apps. I mean there is tones of third party platforms like OneLogin etc but I would like to have something I build myself. Ideally I would like to have some examples of SSO which works with GAFW so I could figure out the rest myself. I read somewhere that building own SSO portal it's not a piece of cake and also found an article that you can create something based on oAuth2.0 instead. So tried research about oAuth2.0 but all documentation I found is about authenticating to the application that I build using Google Apps Credentials, where I want the opposite; to be able to access Google Apps using the app that I build.

Hope someone could direct me to some examples or documentation or explain the process of learning curve to get my head around this project of building SSO for GAFW.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write your own Auth system and become the Identity Provider (IdP), you need to use SAML as that is the only supported method for now.

Here are the  [step by step instructions](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60224?hl=en&ref_topic=6348126)